# Get rows from Pandas DataFrame from index until condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing, series

Let's say I have a Pandas DataFrame:

```
x = pd.DataFrame(data=[5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4,5],columns=['value'])
x
Out[9]: 
    value
0       5
1       4
2       3
3       2
4       1
5       0
6       1
7       2
8       3
9       4
10      5
```

Now, I want to, given an index, find rows in `x` until a condition is met.
For example, if `index = 2`:

```
x.loc[2]
Out[14]: 
value    3
Name: 2, dtype: int64
```

Now I want to, from that `index`, find the next `n` rows where the value is greater than some `threshold`. For example, if the `threshold is 0`, the results should be:

```
x
Out[9]: 
    value
2       3
3       2
4       1
5       0
```

How can I do this?

I have tried:

```
x.loc[2:x['value']>0,:]
```

But of course this will not work because `x['value']>0` returns a boolean array of:

```
Out[20]: 
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5     False
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
Name: value, dtype: bool
```

Comment: How about `x.loc[x['value']>0]`? You could combine that with indexing by `iloc` to get the desired results.

Comment: @AdrianKeister No, because that will return all rows where the value is greater than 0.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) and slicing

```
x.loc[2:x['value'].gt(0).idxmin(),:]

2    3
3    2
4    1
5    0
Name: value
```

Edit:

For a general formula, use

```
index = 7
threshold = 2
x.loc[index:x.loc[index:,'value'].gt(threshold).idxmin(),:]
```

From your description in comments, seemed like you want to begin from `index+1` and not index. So, if that is the case, just use

```
x.loc[index+1:x.loc[index+1:,'value'].gt(threshold).idxmin(),:]
```

Comment: I'm sure you hear this a lot, but you are a genius. Thanks bud.

Comment: Glad I could help ! Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 1):

You want to filter for index greater than your `index=2`, and for `x['value']>=threshold`, and then select the first `n` of these rows, which can be accomplished with `.head(n)`.

Say:

```
idx = 2
threshold = 0
n = 4
x[(x.index>=idx) & (x['value']>=threshold)].head(n)
```

Out:

```
#      value
# 2     3
# 3     2
# 4     1
# 5     0
```

Edit: changed to >=, and updated example to match OP's example.

Edit 2 due to clarification from OP: since `n` is unknown:

```
idx = 2
threshold = 0
x.loc[idx:(x['value']<=threshold).loc[x.index>=idx].idxmax()]
```

This is selecting from the starting `idx`, in this case `idx=2`, up to and including the first row where the condition is not met (in this case index `5`).

Comment: I don't know what `n` is. I need to search from the index until the condition is met and return the found rows. If I knew what `n` was, I could just do `x.loc[idx:n,:]` :)